# certbot-auto certonly --apache works great, but certbot-auto renew on older certs fails

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I inherited a web-server that uses letsencrypt with certbot.  At first I thought it seemed straight forward, but running certbot-auto renew fails.  I then did a certbot-auto certonly --apache and that downloaded a cert just fine (That then running renew again pick ups and even says its new doesnt neeed renewal).  Not sure what I am missing or have yet to learn but some of the failure messages are:
(names changed to protect the innocent)

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log



- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/xyx.someaddress.com-0004.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
Renewing an existing certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for xyx.someaddress.com
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain xyx.someaddress.com
Cleaning up challenges
Attempting to renew cert (xyx.someaddress.com-0004) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/xyx.someaddress.com-0004.conf produced an unexpected error: Some challenges have failed.. Skipping.
All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/xyx.someaddress.com-0004/fullchain.pem (failure)

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:
1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)
Domain: xyx.someaddress.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   https://xyx.someaddress.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/oMvZoCPBM8qZjYcIOlSHs0SLophprew9-c9zASc9d1s
   [192.41.211.157]: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML
   2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>404 Not
   Found</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

So the biggest thing is I see the 'to fix these errors', but what does it mean domain name was entered correctly..where?  and the DNS A/AAA are the right Ip address? No Idea where i check that.   The conf file has many (omitted) domain names in it here but looks like this:

```
[renewalparams]
authenticator = webroot
account = ******************
server = https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
[[webroot_map]]
xyx.someaddress.com = /var/www/html
www.xyx.someaddress.com = /var/www/html
```

Comment: did you get the solution?

Comment: Did you place any htaccess file in your apache directory

Comment: I too stucked and got it resolved after doing few things manually

Comment: I should of updated it, but the server I inherited here I found out finally had like a web firewall infront of the web server itself.  So I had to run certbot on that first, then on the webserver and all was well.  An odd setup I still don't fully understand why/how they configured it that way.